# How to work on complex series with uniform continuity?

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-continuity

I've got a problem to solve. It relates to my homework and I couldn't manage to deal with it.

Prove that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} z^{-2n} 
$$
is uniformly continuous for $\lbrace z:|z|>1 \rbrace$.

I suspect, that i should use theorem from lecture:

1. (Bolzano-wieierstrass theorem):
   $D \in C$, if terms of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(z) , \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$$
   satisfy condition:
   $$\forall_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\text{ }\forall_{z\in \mathbb{C}}\text{  }|f_n(z)|\leq a_n$$
   Then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(z)$ is uniformly continuous, when $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ is continous.

Maybe I'am wrong and more "traditional" way is better:

$$ \forall_{\epsilon>0}\text{ } \exists_{N(\epsilon)}\text{ } \forall_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\text{ } \forall_{z\in \mathbb{D}}\text{ } [n>N(\epsilon) \Longrightarrow |S(z)-S_{n}(z)|<\epsilon]$$

Where: $D\in \mathbb{C}$, $S(z)$- sum of series, $S(z)= \displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_{n}(z)$.

Comment: The series is not even defined at $z=0$. Did you type $z^{-2n}$ for $z^{2n}$?

Comment: I type it correct. Problem have $z^{-2n}$, not $z^{2n}$.

Comment: A function cannot be continuous if it is not even defined there.

Comment: I edited my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By M-Test the series converges uniformly for $\{|z| \geq 1\}$. So $f(z)=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} z^{-2n} 
$ is a continuous function there. Besides$|f(z)| <
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} R^{-2n} 
<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  R^{-2n}=\frac {R^{-2}} {1-R^{-2}}$ for $|z| >R$ and $\frac {R^{-2}} {1-R^{-2}} \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$. Hence, $f(z) \to 0$ as $|z| \to \infty$. This implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous on  $\{|z| \geq 1\}$.